# How to use grub to tripleboot Windows 7, Windows 10 and Ububntu no-UEFI(Legacy), MBR?

Tags: boot, grub2

MBR, all OS's in Legacy(no-UEFI)

I've had got Windows 7 and installed Ubuntu. Later Installed Windows 10. It broke grub, but I've repaired it. The problem is that I've got only one entry in Grub for win - Windows 10(which loads sda1 where win7 was installed, and I guess win loader is there now). So when I choose it the computer now load windows loader and I now have to choose again between two wins.
Is there a way to use grub to choose directly between all 3 OS and not waste time?
I've tried to find some info, but found only one old thread that I may try to repair loaders of each of wins using their install disks and that eliminates their connection in their win loaders, but I'm not sure If it'll work and won't break anything since  there was no confirmation...

Comment: Do you HAVE to use BIOS boot? Does your hardware not support EFI?

Comment: The best way I have found to do this, since I do not use UEFI as well, is to have a separate drive for each OS.  After all was setup on my system I then put my Ubuntu drive as the primary boot.   The only time I put one of the other drives, like Win 7 or Win 10 as primary is only during its install.  After that, I switch back to Ubuntu as primary and I have never had GRUB issues or boot issues since.  Just make sure to run `sudo update-grub` after a new OS install and boot back to Ubuntu.

Comment: If both Windows are in primary NTFS partitions, you can move boot flag & run repairs. Then each will have boot files and grub2's os-prober will find them separately. But if not primary partition, Windows will not repair it. And Windows 10's fast start up must remain off. It may turn it back on with udpates. Best to retire Windows 7. And if UEFI hardware, reinstall in UEFI boot mode. A user who installed two windows & it worked to boot from grub directly
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1271600

Comment: Win 7 is out of support and probably not safe to use on internet.